# Any progress on separating public and jobs location?

Tags: support, feature-request, profile-page, developer-story

According to [balpha's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320594/9746775) (posted on 2016-04-07)

> Now, your point about not making the location public (i.e. to only show it to employers interested in hiring you, but not everyone viewing your Stack Overflow profile) is absolutely valid.
>
> (...)
>
> eventually, we'll make it possible to enter two different things, say, a rough location (e.g. country) or nothing at all in the public profile, but a more specific location in the Developer Story (which would necessarily have to be hidden in that case, otherwise it would be pointless).

but as far as I can tell, such separation still haven't been implemented. Are there any updates on that front? ETA?